# nested namespaces in lua

Tags: lua, namespaces

I'm just getting my feet wet with some Lua in an embedded interpreter (so I don't have a lot of control over the environment). The existing Lua scripting infrastructure is something we get from an external vendor so

1. I don't want to change it except in emergencies and
2. I want to keep my code cleanly separated from the vendors.

Their strategy is to load a lot of modules into the global namespace -- they have lot of module files which effectively do

```
modulename = modulename or {}
modulename.something = function()
    ...
end
```

which is find insofar as it presents the API i have to work with and everything is easy to get to.  However I'm sure I'll run into name clashes; if I make my own module called X and they have a module X already, I end up adding to it (and the code lives in different places, so I could easily do this inadvertently).

What I'd like to do is a single root namespace with all of my modules being part of that, so I'm insulated cleanly and don't have to worry about accidentally overwriting the core api.

What I've got so far is like this:

```
root = root or {}
root.modulename = require('path to module')
   -- etc...
return root
```

as my root namespace and then

```
local modulename = {}
function modulename.something()
      return "foo"
end 
return modulename
```

which appears to give me the isolation I want: I can do

```
root.modulename.something()
```

in the interpreter get my "foo".

However I'd appreciate knowing what gotchas this may entail and if there's a more common solution.  And what's likely to happen if `root.othermodule` wants to use a member of `root.modulename` -- will I have manually manage the load order?

Comment: You are on the right track. You may find this blog post helpful (from the author of LuaRocks) http://hisham.hm/2014/01/02/how-to-write-lua-modules-in-a-post-module-world/

Comment: In Lua 5.1 you can "clone" global environment by executing the following line: `root.root = root; setfenv(0, setmetatable(root, {__index=_G})); setfenv(1, root); orig_G = _G; _G = root`. From now on `modulename` is mapped to your `root.modulename`, and original module (that was shadowed) is available as `orig_G.modulename`

Comment: Why use `return root` if it's already a global?

Comment: Require all your modules and place what they return in `root`... I don't see any problems with this.

Comment: @DavisDude -- Honestly, it's because that's what the vendor code does - it looked to me like a guard against unintended reloads but i'm not enough of a Lua person to know if it has non-obvious side-effects I can't forsee

Comment: @theodox It really doesn't matter much, as long as when you require the file you use the same name, which, if not done, could lead to some confusion. Aside from that, locals are slightly faster than globals, of course usually the difference is trivial.

Comment: The `return X` is so that `require` stores the module in the correct locations as well as just having the global be set. It is the way post-5.1 modules are supposed to work (and they are not supposed to expect the global to be set or to set it).

Comment: This seems sane enough of a policy to me and yes, you will need to manage inter-module dependencies yourself (or write your own "loader" that handles it for you). That said that only matters if a module needs another module during loading and not at a later time (assuming you always load everything when you are first loaded).